# Debugging "mem_used_percent" on EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, memory-management, memory-leaks, amazon-cloudwatch

We are facing a peculiar issue in our AWS service running on EC2 instances. In CW metrics "mem_used_percent" is gradually going up with time and eventually goes to 90% followed by system failure. We have verified that failure is happening due to OOM error and restarting the hosts is fixing it by bringing the "mem_used_percent" down to around 20%.

While doing the investigation on new and old running EC2 instances, we are seeing that only around 20% of the RAM usage is accounted for in "top" command output(sort by %MEM). We are not able to actually pin-point the processes using rest of the unaccounted physical memory.

Is there a better way to do memory usage analysis on EC2 instances(Linux) that will sum up to "mem_used_percent" in CW metrics?

Please let me know if any other details are required.

Thanks!!

Comment: did you find out the reason for this? I'm seeing the same behavior in M5.large instance type.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "procstat plugin". It might help your investigation

"The procstat plugin enables you to collect metrics from individual processes".

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-procstat-process-metrics.html#CloudWatch-Agent-procstat-process-metrics-collected